# How to take automatically value from textbox

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to scan a card to a textbox and I want to take value from the textbox when the scanning complete.

When I try this its execute before scan completion.

```
private void txtUserName_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string val = txtUserName.Text;
}
```

Comment: What is the problem with the code? What is the expected behavior and actual one? The cosde you've provided will be executed on *every change* of `txtUserName` textbox.

Comment: What kind of scanning are you doing? Since there is no if-statements or anything like that to make sure the scanning is done. Can you provide more code? :) or explain the problem in more detailed way. :)

Comment: The event is probably firing as each character is entered - so you may have to look for a specific length (if this is fixed)  or terminating character (if it can be configured).

Comment: You, usually, get a `\r\n` (or `\n`) at the end of the code. When you get an *Enter*, the code is complete. Or configure the scanner to return custom/specific prefixes/suffixes.

Comment: yes, it's happening for each change, we can't give length because it's not fixed.so please suggest some other idea for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to choose some special character which will indicate completion of a scan.

Currently your code will store in `val` variable any text that is in `TextBox` after changing text in it. Including situation when you are typing last character of your input, so your code would work eventually.

But I'd suggest choosing for example `\t` character and then checking for scan completion indicated by this character using `KeyPress` event (because event arguments have `KeyChar`, which is very useful):

```
private void txtUserName_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.KeyChar != '\t') return;
  // handle your event
}
```

Comment: Will the WinForms textbox get a KeyPress event when tab is entered - wont this just move to the next control?

Comment: You need to set `e.Handled = true` to prevent from focusing another control.

Comment: I have just tested & as I suspected there is no KeyPress event for tab. There is a KeyUp event when the control receives focus due to tab, but no KeyDown event either. Using tab would also require the scanner to be configured to terminate with that character which may or may not be an option - typically \r or \r\n can be configured, so \r may be a better character to look for.